# If $16$ equal isosceles right triangles are combined into convex polygon then rational side of one does not lie along irrational side of another

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

How can we prove, using algebra, that if $16$ equal isosceles right triangles are combined into a convex polygon, then a rational side of one triangle does not lie along an irrational side of another?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? How have you tried solving it? What methods are you familiar to use in this kind of situation?

Comment: I know that the rational and irrational sides don't tessellate, but I really do not know how I can prove this